# Wordpress url from category page

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, permalinks

I like to use the current category name in url when a post has multiple categories linking from a category page. This is a working example:

```
global $post;
$cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_slug = $cat->slug;
$post_slug = $post->post_name;

<?php echo get_site_url() . '/'.$cat_slug.'/'.$post_slug.'/'; ?>
```

but is this the best solution? Or is there a better way? Still learning...

(Permalink settings: /%category%/%postname%/ and a "." in the optional part)

Comment: You should post this on code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I will do